React Query: How can I disable a query based on whether there is data in the database?
I'm using a simple custom hook to fill in a form with data that a user may have previously entered in previous sessions.
export function useGetData() {
     return useQuery({
       queryFn: fetchFormData,
       queryKey: ['form-data'],
       enabled: [what to put here, if anything?]
}

The problem I'm having is I don't want it to query if the data in the database is currently empty, i.e. the user entering the page for the first time, or just not filling the form out until a later date. The React Query docs show parameters in the query function as something to pass in the enabled property, but my case doesn't suit that example. Any help is appreciated.

How will you know there’s no data before you query?

I think that's my source of confusion that might be as much of a web development question as it is a React Query question: Will there always be network requests regardless of whether there is or isn't any data to query? If there is no way to around that, which is fine, how could I prevent the loading state from visually displaying (like a spinner or a skeleton) before it returns null?

If only the server knows whether the data exists, then there will need to be a network request. And since you can't predict the future, you will need to either always show the loading state, or always not show the loading state while you wait for that network request.
